# accessing integer value from -(int) method [cocos2d]

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am calling upon [self birdtouched:2] when the bird is touched, which returns 2.

```
-(int) birdTouched: (int) number {

if (number == 1){return 1;}
if (number ==2){return 2;}
if (number ==3){return 3;}

else return 0;}
```

I want to create an if statement in another method like;

```
if ("value of birdTouched == 2) { YADA YADA;}
```

I am a new developer, so easy concepts like this are hard for me to grasp.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ([self birdTouched:birdNumber] == 2) { /* YADA YADA */ }
```

Comment: Since  [self birdtouched:2] is only input when the bird it touched, would I need some sort of update function in my other method?

Comment: I don't know since this is nothing about this your question. This code should go in the input checking function of the game loop.